# what is the difference between these movw to AX and movb to AL load instructions, from an odd offset in .short array?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

```
.global main

.data
arr: .short 1, 0xEA, 0x2, 0x3, 0b1010

.text
main:

      lea (arr), %rbx
      movb 3(%rbx),%al #1

      movw arr+3, %ax #2
```

when I try this code `al` gets the value `0x0` however `ax` gets the value `0x200`
can you tell me why is that? what is the difference between #1 and #2 ?

Comment: Same load address (both inefficiently using 32-bit absolute addressing, not RIP-relative), but one merges one byte into the bottom of RAX, while the other merges 2 bytes (a word).

Comment: The difference should be obvious, the first one only loads `al` (the low 8 bits) while the second loads `ax` (16 bits). Note that `al` is zero in both cases as expected. The `3(%rbx)` and the `arr+3` do the same the important thing is the `movb` vs the `movw`. Furthermore assembly uses byte addressing and `.short` is 2 bytes so `arr+3` is the high byte of `0xEA` (which is zero) and is addressing misaligned.

Comment: We've had previous Q&As about misaligned loads and what data you get, some with good answers.  I can't find one right now, though, and not sure there's a duplicate that also covers the obvious 1 vs. 2-byte load difference explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since x86 is a little-endian architecture, the data in `arr` looks like:

```
arr+0   +1   +2   +3   +4   +5   +6   +7   +8   +9
 0x01 0x00 0xEA 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x0A 0x00
```

#1 reads data to `al`. `al` is a one-byte register, so `0x00` at the `+3` is loaded and the value becomes `0x0`.

#2 reads data to `ax`. `ax` is a two-byte register, so `0x00 0x02` is loaded and the value becomes `0x200`.

The difference is the size of the destination registers.